# Make a synonym table

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

So I have a df containing codes and names associated with these codes. Basically, the codes are unique but may have multiple names. So, if you want to `left_join()` with another table without creating duplicate rows, you need to reorganize the table. I want to do it so that it is grouped by codes and the columns are "name1", "name2" etc.

**input df**

```
df<-data.frame(code=c(1,1,2),
                 name=c("a", "b", "c"))
```

**result df**

```
resdf<-data.frame(code=c(1,2),
                  name1=c("a", "c"),
                  name2=c("b",""))
```

I don't care if the unique values are filled with NAs or ""s or whatever.

I can't find a good solution using aggregate etc. and am stumped.

Comment: Are you sure the data.frame is the right object for this ? Because you could had a lot of synonym and thus columns, maybe a list is more fit for this kind of data ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `name1 = c("a", "b")` and `name2 = c("c", "")` in resdf??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without external packages, you could use `reshape()`.

```r
reshape(transform(df, id = ave(code, code, FUN = seq_along)),
        direction = "wide", idvar = "code", timevar = "id", v.names = "name")

#   code name.1 name.2
# 1    1      a      b
# 3    2      c   <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `pivot_wider` after creating a variable that identifies the sequential numbers for each code.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_by(code) |> 
  mutate(sequential = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "name",
              names_from = "sequential",
              values_from = "name")
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   code [2]
#>    code name1 name2
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 a     b    
#> 2     2 c     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't you need to add `ungroup()` at the end to turn it back to `tbl_df` from `grouped_df` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving your problem based on data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

mx = max(setDT(df)[, .N, code]$N)

df[, setNames(as.list(name)[1:mx], paste0("name", 1:mx)), code]

    code  name1  name2
1:     1      a      b
2:     2      c   <NA>
```